# What is the difference between iOS Distribution and APNs Production iOS profiles?

Tags: iphone, ios

Using developer.apple.com I can see in

iOS Certificates (Development)
Two profiles with the following description

- iOS Distribution

  APNs Production iOS

I would like to know what is the difference, and which one I should save to include in my xCode project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APNS Provisioning  Profiles are for Apple Push Notifications. 
You shouldn't bother with them unless you are setting up an app that pushes notifications using APNS.

The one you need, for a general XCode project/iOS app, is a general iOS Distribution Provisioning Profile.